# How do I style the value of an attribute on a Woocommerce shop product / archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, advanced-custom-fields

How do I adjust the code below to do the following?:

a. Both **Brand** and **Intensity** is showing the attribute of **Profile**, rather than their own attributes. 
b. Styling only the attribute **value** part of the attribute and not
the attribute **label** part. 
c. Move the attributes to below the **Product name**, at the moment they appear above it.

Thank you very much. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
function add_attribute() {
    global $product;

    $product_attributes = array( 'pa_brand', 'pa_intensity', 'pa_profile');
    $attr_output = array();

    foreach( $product_attributes as $taxonomy ){
        if( taxonomy_exists($taxonomy) ){
            $label_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
            $value = $product->get_attribute('pa_brand');
            $value = $product->get_attribute('pa_intensity');
            $value = $product->get_attribute('pa_profile');

            if( ! empty($value) ){
                $attr_output[] = '<span class="'.$taxonomy.'">'.$label_name.': '.$value.'</span>';
            }
        }
    }

    echo '<div style="color:red;">'.implode( '<br>', $attr_output ).'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the following plugin: **WooCommerce Show Attributes**

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-show-attributes/